# How to stream in and manipulate a large data file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I have a relatively large (1 GB) text file that I want to cut down in size by summing across categories:

```
Geography AgeGroup Gender Race Count
County1   1        M      1    12
County1   2        M      1    3
County1   2        M      2    0
```

To:

```
Geography Count
County1   15
County2   23
```

This would be a simple matter if the whole file could fit in memory but using `pandas.read_csv()` gives `MemoryError`. So I have been looking into other methods, and there appears to be many options - HDF5? Using `itertools` (which seems complicated - generators?) Or just using the standard file methods to read in the first geography (70 lines), sum the count column, and write out before loading in another 70 lines.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this? I especially like the idea of streaming data in, especially because I can think of a lot of other places where this would be useful. I am most interested in this method, or one that similarly uses the most basic functionality possible.

**Edit:** In this small case I only want the sums of count by geography. However, it would be ideal if I could read in a chunk, specify any function (say, add 2 columns together, or take the max of a column by geography), apply the function, and write the output before reading in a new chunk.

Comment: Do you know about [chunked reads in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk)? `pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', chunksize=1000)`. Then you can operate on pieces within a loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), which is syntactically similar to `pandas`, but performs manipulations out-of-core, so memory shouldn't be an issue:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
df = df.groupby('Geography')['Count'].sum().to_frame()
df.to_csv('my_output.csv')
```

Alternatively, if `pandas` is a requirement you can use chunked reads, as mentioned by @chrisaycock.  You may want to experiment with the `chunksize` parameter.

```
# Operate on chunks.
data = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', chunksize=10**5):
    chunk = chunk.groupby('Geography', as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
    data.append(chunk)

# Combine the chunked data.
df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
df = df.groupby('Geography')['Count'].sum().to_frame()
df.to_csv('my_output.csv')
```

Answer (score 4):

I do like @root's solution, but i would go bit further optimizing memory usage - keeping only aggregated DF in memory and reading only those columns, that you really need:

```
cols = ['Geography','Count']
df = pd.DataFrame()

chunksize = 2   # adjust it! for example --> 10**5
for chunk in (pd.read_csv(filename,
                          usecols=cols,
                          chunksize=chunksize)
             ):
    # merge previously aggregated DF with a new portion of data and aggregate it again
    df = (pd.concat([df,
                     chunk.groupby('Geography')['Count'].sum().to_frame()])
            .groupby(level=0)['Count']
            .sum()
            .to_frame()
         )

df.reset_index().to_csv('c:/temp/result.csv', index=False)
```

test data:

```
Geography,AgeGroup,Gender,Race,Count
County1,1,M,1,12
County2,2,M,1,3
County3,2,M,2,0
County1,1,M,1,12
County2,2,M,1,33
County3,2,M,2,11
County1,1,M,1,12
County2,2,M,1,111
County3,2,M,2,1111
County5,1,M,1,12
County6,2,M,1,33
County7,2,M,2,11
County5,1,M,1,12
County8,2,M,1,111
County9,2,M,2,1111
```

output.csv:

```
Geography,Count
County1,36
County2,147
County3,1122
County5,24
County6,33
County7,11
County8,111
County9,1111
```

PS using this approach will you can process huge files.

PPS using chunking approach should work unless you need to sort your data - in this case i would use classic UNIX tools, like `awk`, `sort`, etc. for sorting your data first

I would also recommend to use PyTables (HDF5 Storage), instead of CSV files - it is very fast and allows you to read data conditionally (using `where` parameter), so it's very handy and saves a lot of resources and usually [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python/37012035#37012035) compared to CSV.