# Multiple External Processes Reading From the Same Data Source

Tags: python, pandas, io, multiprocessing

I have a situation where I have multiple sources that will need to read from the same (small in size) data source, possibly at the same time.  For example, multiple different computers calling a function that needs to read from an external data source (e.g. excel file).  Since it multiple different sources are involved, I cannot simply read from the data source once and pass it into the function---it must be loaded in the function.

Is there a data source that can handle this effectively?  A pandas dataframe was an acceptable format for information that need to be read so I tried storing that dataframe in an sqlite3 databases since according to the sqlite3 website, sqlite3 databases can handle concurrent reads.  Unfortunately, it is failing too often. I tried multiple different iterations and simply could not get it to work.

Is there another data format/source that would work/be effective?  I tried scouring the internet for whether or not something as simple as an excel file + the pandas read_excel function could handle this type of concurrency but I could not find information.  I tried an experiment of using a multiprocessing pool to simultaneously load the same very large (i.e. 1 minute load) excel file and it did not crash.  But of course, that is not exactly a perfect experiment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [openpyxl's read-only mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html). It uses generator instead of loading whole file.

Also take a look at [processing large xlsx file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208137/processing-large-xlsx-file-in-python)